# Crucible - Smart commits do not work for large repositories

Tags: atlassian-crucible

Smart commits either do not work or works with lag with large repositories. Reviews are created sporadically. The smart commit works on certain branches and not others. Have you seen experienced such nuances, and if so, what would be an option to try?

Answer (score 0):

Large repositories take a lot of time to index, especially if you have lot of feature branches. The lag is because it takes time for crucible to index all that data

1. You can try 2 things , You can force crucible to run a smart index on a large repository ahead of time
2. In case your repository is large because you have too many feature branches, try cleaning up your feature branches after a release . We ran into this issue where we had too many feature branches. Once we started cleaning this up , our indexing ran a lot faster and the lag time reduced significantly

I have not seen smart commits not working on branches. In case you have a specific branching scheme that crucible is monitoring and your new branch does not match that pattern crucible will not monitor it. For ex if your crucible is setup to monitor all branches whose name starts with "feature" and your branch name does not start with feature it will not be monitored, period